# Android image To text implementation

Tags: android, ocr, image-recognition

I'm working on an app that would take a picture of a  15 numbers on a scratch card and then write these numbers to screen .

I have looked into some of the OCR libs around but most of them are very cpu intensive since they are built for full image to text .

so what would be an ideal implementation for such thing . would it be possible to just take pictures of each number store it in the app and
then find each number by comparing it to the stock pictures i have .

In other terms would it be possible to search for a bitmap in this case the stock image that i have of each number within another bitmap ( the picture taken from the camera )